# «Стала пуганной птица-удача...» Или пуганой?

Tags: орфография, нн

Как правильно? Надо же с двумя Н, так как *пугать* — несов. вид, не правда ли?

> Стала пуга**нн**ой птица-удача — и не верит людским рукам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм ответа на такой вопрос следующий:

1. Сперва определяется часть речи, которой является слово "пуганой" - стала какой? пуганой.
   Видим, что это слово обозначает признак предмета и производно от глагола пугать, следовательно, оно может быть как прилагательным, так и причастием, что означает возможность написания как -Н, так и -НН в зависимости от контекста.
2. Для того чтобы решить орфографическую задачу сколько букв Н писать в таком слове, требуется:

а) убедиться, что это слово не является словарным

б) опрелелить вид глагола, от которого образовано слово (у причастия это СВ), в нашем случае это НСВ

в) выявить наличие/отсутствие производителя действия в Т.п. или зависимых слов, которые делают это слово причастием (стала пуганной человеком птица, стала пуганной выстрелами), в нашем случае этого не наблюдается

г) подобрать однородное определение-прилагательное, которое могло бы сочетаться с нашим словом по смыслу: стала боязливой, пуганой

На основании всего вышеперечисленного прийти к выводу, что это качественное прилагательное, образованное от бесприставочного глагола НСВ, применить правило правописания прилагательных, образованных от глагола, и написать в этом слове одну букву Н. Таким образом, "стала пуганой птица удачи".

Comment: Это не качественное прилагательное, это отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: Максим: Прилагательное мы узнаем по лексическому признаку: оно приобретает качественное значение и может быть заменено синонимом. https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=199902601

Comment: Интересно, что у слова могут быть разные значения (сайт Грамота.ру): Орфографический словарь: пуганый, прил.

Большой толковый словарь
ПУГАНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Такой, которого часто пугали; напуганный. * Пуганая ворона куста боится (Посл.). 2. Разг. Такой, которого трудно чём-л. испугать. Уже пуганый, не испугаешь!